# Bash, Netcat, Pipes, perl

Tags: regex, perl, bash, csv, pipe

**Background:** I have a fairly simple `bash` script that I'm using to generate a `CSV` log file.  As part of that bash script I poll other devices on my network using `netcat`.  The `netcat` command returns a stream of information that I can pipe that into a `grep` command to get to certain values I need in the `CSV` file.  I save that return value from `grep` into a `bash` variable and then at the end of the script, I write out all saved `bash` variables to a `CSV` file. (Simple enough.)

The change I'd like to make is the amount of `netcat` commands I have to issue for each piece of information I want to save off.  With each issued `netcat` command I get ALL possible values returned (so each time returns the same data and is burdensome on the network).  So, I'd like to only use `netcat` once and parse the return value as many times as I need to create the `bash` variables that can later be concatenated together into a single record in the `CSV` file I'm creating.

**Specific Question:** Using `bash` syntax if I pass the output of the `netcat` command to a file using `>` (versus the current `grep`method) I get a file with each entry on its own line (presumably separated with the `\n` as the EOL record separator -- easy for perl regex).  However, if I save the output of `netcat` directly to a `bash` variable, and echo that variable, all of the data is jumbled together, so it is cumbersome to parse out (not so easy).

I have played with two options: First, I think a perl one-liner may be a good solution here, but I'm not sure how to best execute it.  Pseudo code might be to save the `netcat` output to a a bash variable and then somehow figure out how to parse it with perl (not straight forward though).

The second option would be to use `bash`'s `>` and send `netcat`'s output to a file.  This would be easy to process with `perl` and Regex given the `\n` `EOL`, but that would require opening an external file and passing it to a `perl` script for processing AND then somehow passing its return value back into the `bash` script as a `bash` variable for entry into the `CSV` file.

I know I'm missing something simple here.  Is there a way I can force a newline entry into the `bash` variable from `netcat` and then repeatedly run a perl-one liner against that variable to create each of the `CSV` variables I need -- all within the same `bash` script?  Sorry, for the long question.

Comment: Too many words, not enough code

Comment: I bet you're able to write a *specific question* **as** a *specific question* -- one sentence, or two. Also, show us some code, in and output, and point what is going wrong with your approach.

Comment: You guys complaining about too many words and not enough code... Stop being lazy. secJ was trying to be as detailed about his problem as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The second option would be to use bash's > and send netcat's output to
>   a file. This would be easy to process with perl and Regex given the \n
>   EOL, but that would require opening an external file and passing it to
>   a perl script for processing AND then somehow passing its return value
>   back into the bash script as a bash variable for entry into the CSV
>   file.

This is actually a fairly common idiom: save the output from netcat in
a temporary file, then use grep or awk or perl or what-have-you as
many times as necessary to extract data from that file:

```
# create a temporary file and arrange to have it 
# deleted when the script exists.
tmpfile=$(mktemp tmpXXXXXX)
trap "rm -f $tmpfile" EXIT

# dump data from netcat into the
# temporary file.
nc somehost someport > $tmpfile

# extract some information into variable `myvar`
myvar=$(awk '/something/ {print $4}' $tmpfile)
```

That last line demonstrates how to get the output of something (in this case, an `awk` script) into a variable.  If you were using perl to extract some information you could do the same thing.

You could also just write the whole script in perl, which might make your life easier.

Comment: Thank you!  The last line is exactly what I was trying to get at. I knew there had to be an easier way.  I agree with converting the entire script to perl.  I'm in the process of converting it now, but need to have a temporary fix on the production side while I do. I am currently running the script in a while loop, so it doesn't EXIT per se, but I should be able to remove the temp file easily within the script after each time through the loop, then recreate it at the next go around. Thanks again!